# How to check if request is for static content in play framework in scala?

Tags: scala, playframework, cache-control

Im working with play framework 2.1 and I need to know when there was a request for static content(js, css) to enable caching...  How can I get it from the request object in play?

Thanks

Answer (score 0):

PlayFramework already provides caching for public assets (aka static contents)

> Play 2.0 comes with a built-in controller to serve public assets. By default, this controller provides caching, ETag, gzip compression and JavaScript minification support.

More details here: https://www.playframework.com/documentation/2.1.x/Assets#The-Assets-controller